# How create a variable if not exist in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

I searched many websites to find how to make variable in php if it's not exist. But what I found just how to set value from variable like:

```
<?PHP $z=$_POST['Haha']; $var=""; if(empty($var) || $var==""){ $var = $z } ?>
```

What I want like:

```
<?PHP $z=$_POST['Haha']; if(not exist $var with name $z){ create $var with name $z and set value = ""} ?>
```

If folder doesn't exist we use mkdir. If variable doesn't exist, what we use to make?

Can someone give me solution?
Sory for my bad english and thanks before.

Comment: you need to use `isset`

Comment: you got some advance with your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not exist the var $Haha create the var and assign a value:

```
<?php

$_POST['text'] = "Haha" ;

if(!isset($$_POST['text'])) {
    $$_POST['text'] = 'WOW';
}   

echo $Haha;

?>
```

Comment: @MukhlisSaputro you got some advance?

Comment: Haha.. Sory. Newbie XD. Thanks :)

Comment: @MukhlisSaputro and if you see any answer usefull for you you can upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Use isset();

```
if(!isset($_POST['Haha'])){
    $z = "";
}else{
    $z = $_POST['Haha'];
}
```

UPD:

```
//$_POST['haha'] = myNewVar
if(isset($_POST['haha'])){
    $createVar = array($_POST['haha']);
    extract($createVar);
    $myNewVar = "Congratulations!";
}
echo $myNewVar;
```

Comment: Thanks. But not set value with $_POST. I want to make variabel by name from $_POST. If $_POST['text'] = "Haha" create variabel $haha. If $_POST['text'] = "hihi" create variabel $hihi. Si variable name depends on what value from post.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear but it sounds like you need to use PHP's `isset` and `mkdir` functions with your post data.

```
<?php

$z = '';
if(isset($_POST['Haha']){
    //Assign Value of Haha to variable z
    $z = $_POST['Haha'];
} else {
    //we can make our variable z a default value if no $_POST data is recieved
    $z = 'default';
}
//check for existence of variable on directory path
if(is_dir("/path/to/my/dir/".$z)) {
    echo "Directory Exists";
} else {
    //You will need to append the variable z onto the directory path to create the directory
    mkdir("/path/to/my/dir/".$z , 0777);
    echo "Directory Created";
}

?>
```

Comment: I want to make variabel by name from $_POST. So, if $_POST['Haha'], it will make $haha = " ".

Comment: To construct your variable by POST name you can use `extract($_POST);` If you want to view your variable `$haha` just `echo get_defined_vars();`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single line setting the variable as one thing if set and setting it as something if not.

```
<?php
    $z = ( isset( $_POST['haha'] ) ) ? "Set" : "not set";
```